# How to get data from observable in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

I am trying to print the result of `http` call in `Angular` using `rxjs`

Consider the following code

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
class myHTTPService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  configEndPoint: string = '/my_url/get_config';

  getConfig() {

    return this.http
      .get(this.configEndPoint)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './myTemplate',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, myHTTPService],


})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService: myHTTPService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.myService.getConfig());
    }
}
```

Whenever I tried to print out the result of `getconfig` it always return

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

even though I return a json object instead.

How would I print out the result of `getConfig` ?

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 124):

You need to subscribe to the observable and pass a callback that processes emitted values

```ts
this.myService.getConfig().subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: its `res.json()` instead of `res.json`

Comment: hmm. but have't mentioned it so post comment

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last comment. It's already in the code in the question. No deed to convert to JSON again when you subscribe.

Comment: hmm i just wan to say we need to conver into .json() at the time or .map().

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(val))

Answer (score 28):

Angular is based on observable instead of promise base as of angularjs 1.x, so when we try to get data using `http` it returns observable instead of promise, like you did

```
 return this.http
      .get(this.configEndPoint)
      .map(res => res.json());
```

then to get data and show on view we have to convert it into desired form using RxJs functions like `.map() function and .subscribe()`

.map() is used to convert the observable (received from http request)to any form like `.json(), .text()`  as stated in Angular's official website,

.subscribe() is used to subscribe those observable response and ton put into some variable so from which we display it into the view

```
this.myService.getConfig().subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
   this.data = res;
});
```

Comment: What if service is taking time to return the data and you need to use the this.data in your next function ?

Comment: then you can use aync/await or you can call your next function within the http service call. both ways should work.

Answer (score 18):

```
this.myService.getConfig().subscribe(
  (res) => console.log(res),
  (err) => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('done!')
);
```