# HTTP Service call bind to HTML elements

Tags: angular

I have a HTML page where i am displaying list of patient. (list called from service call to json server). when user clicks on a patient,it should display the details of the page.

in the services

```
getPatientList(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(endpoint).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log( JSON.stringify(data)))
 );
}

getPatientDetails(id: number): Observable<any> {
      return this.getPatientList().pipe(
      map((patient: any[]) => patient.find(p => p.profile_no === id))
      );
}
```

patient-details.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-patient-details',
  templateUrl: './patient-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./patient-details.component.css']
})
export class PatientDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  patient : any;
  pId: number;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {


    this.data.getPatientDetails(this.pId).subscribe(
      patient => this.patient = patient);
    console.log(this.patient);
  }
}
console.log(patient) display following in console.


Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

here is the part of HTML template

```
<div class="form-group child">
      <h1>{{patient.first_name}} {{patient.last_name}}</h1>
    <div class="col form-group form-control-md mt-5">
      <label for="profileNo" style="width:25%">Profile No: </label>
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm" [(ngModel)]="patient.profile_no"> 
    </div>  
    <div class="col form-group form-control-md">
      <label for="DOB" style="width:25%">Date of Birth: </label> 
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm" [(ngModel)]="patient.DOB">
    </div> 
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="gender" style="width:25%">Gender: </label>
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm"[(ngModel)]="patient.gender"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="bloodGroup" style="width:25%">Blood Group: </label>
      <input type="text" class="input-group-sm" [(ngModel)]="patient.blood_group"> 
    </div>
```

Comment: explain your problem

Comment: please post the HTML template where you are binding, and post the .TS class as well.

Comment: edited with html template and ts

Comment: Could you please tell, how's your `Id` is injected to the `endpoint` ? means if you try to test your service with a native consumer (e.g: postman), how'll pass that `id` ? : `endpoint/id` , `endpoint?id=id` ...

Comment: i have run the json server. on json server when i run the following it gives me full detail of patient.  http://localhost:3000/patient-details?profile_no=1

Answer (score 0):

I think first two methods (services) should be refactored to :

```
getPatientList(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(`${endpoint}`);
}
```

And :

```
getPatientDetails(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(`${endpoint}?profile_no=${id}`);
}
```

Comment: @khushi, btw, and normally should not give the same error, if u'd subscribed on the service. Do you use `Http` or `HttpClient` in your class service ?

Comment: it is httpclient

Comment: @khushi Based on what u'd provided, should work, even if that doesnt work your `console.log(patient)` should not give `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`, verify , rerun ur server maybe.

Comment: i tried re-running, same error. appriciate if you can give me other solutions.

Comment: it return same observable object Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}

Comment: @khushi  Provide a stackblitz at least , remote debugging is a super-men feature :p. There's no "OTHER" solution, there's an issue with ur code :), the provided solution should work in normal cases. –

Comment: @khushi and have a look here to know what I meant by should not give the same console : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395252/how-to-get-data-from-observable-in-angular2

Comment: thanks will look into it. this is my first post on stackoverflow. what do you mean by stackblitz? i appreciate all your help for remote debugging.

Comment: how do you i upoad my existing code in stackblitz.com

Comment: i am done with uploading my code to stackblitz. how do i run the json server in that?

Comment: This seems to be the link to the *running* application instead of to the editor with the code so we can see?

Comment: The error I see in the stackblitz is: `The selector "app-root" did not match any elements`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpatyh please help me on this now. i dont have idea how i would run json server on stackblitz

Comment: Creating a stackblitz to help resolve your issue is meant to just SHOW YOUR ISSUE. Not provide all of your code. Otherwise it is quite time consuming for us to try to find your issue in all of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow!

One error in your code that I see is that you are trying to display a value *before* retrieving it.

This code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getPatientDetails(this.pId).subscribe(
      patient => this.patient = patient);
    console.log(this.patient);
  }
```

Should be this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getPatientDetails(this.pId).subscribe(
      patient => {
         this.patient = patient;
         console.log(this.patient);
      });
  }
```

The logging needs to be *in* the subscribe.

The subscribe tells your service to send an Http request. Immediately after submitting that request, displaying the value will always be undefined.

At some later point in time, the data is returned and the code within the subscribe is executed. So at this point, your `patient` data is set and you can log it.

Other than that, I'm not sure what you are having problems with.

If you could post the link to your stackblitz editing session (instead of to the running code), we could take a look and provide further assistance.

Comment: The point here is that, he/she says the error is always `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}` which does not make sens (for me at least), the issue you're trying to resolve should be `undefined` , ain't it ?

Comment: That does not look like an "error"? But you are right, if that is what displays in the console, it must be coming from somewhere *other* than the shown code.

Comment: The solution by DeborahK worked partially. but now the code is returning empty array.

Comment: this is what my json server returns with the query http://localhost:3000/patient-details?profile_no=1[
  {
    "profile_no": 1,
    "first_name": "Jeanette",
    "last_name": "Penddreth",
    "DOB": "4/24/1990",
    "gender": "Female",
    "insurance_no": "INS7346",
    "blood_group": "B +"
  }
]